# get a file using SFTP with cURL

Tags: php, curl, ftp, sftp

I cant seem to be able to download a file through SFTP using cURL.

```
    $c = curl_init("sftp://$user:$pass@/someserver.com/$filename");
    $fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die($php_errormsg);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
    curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
```

Am i doing something wrong? Thanks a lot for your help

Michelle

Comment: `curl_error()` can be used to see errors

Comment: What's the error you're getting? If it's a blank screen, put some echo or printf statements in your code and see which line it's failing on.

Answer (score 2):

yeah, you have a / proceeding your domain name.

```
$c = curl_init("sftp://$user:$pass@someserver.com/$filename");
$fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die($php_errormsg);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

Answer (score 1):

The libcurl in use on this server has to have sftp support compiled in. Looking at the return code will tell you whether it's supported or not. If not, then you'll have to ask the server administrator to upgrade libcurl.